# CORS: Browser not expsoing `location` header even though it's allowed in the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`

Tags: javascript, browser, cors

I've been doing some work to configure CORS on my API server to restrict access.  I'm currently serving the following headers for `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` from the options preflight.

```
access-control-allow-headers: location,x-correlation-id,content-range,authorization,accept,content-type,origin
```

Full OPTIONS preflight response:
[image]

However, when doing a POST where it returns a 201 response, the location header is not visible in my Axios response object in javascript.  This appears to be caused by the browser rejecting the location header based on the CORS policy.  I'm not sure what I'm missing that would allow the location header to pass-through to the browser.

POST Response
[image]

console.log of the response object in code.
[image]

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` refers to request headers. `Location` is a response header, which is only sent with redirect responses.

Comment: @Barmar - [`Location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/http/headers/location) relates to 201 (the status the OP is getting), but you're right about `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`.

Comment: @TJ L - Please textual information **as text**, not just as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was I needed to send a [Access-Control-Expose-Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers) in the CORS response and specify the location there.  Doing that exposed the header to the browser and life is good.